# Insert a button in the grouping header

Tags: extjs

Any help would be appreciable.I want to know how to insert a button in the grouping header without using "Ext.ux.grid.RowActions".I am in need of how to put a button in simply by renderer or something like that..Please help me to figure out this.

Comment: What are you talking about? You probably want to add some more tags.

Comment: Seems to be a question about ExtJS, not a question about PHP.  Retagged.

Comment: Please be more specific. Where do you exactly want the button ?

Answer (score 2):

Ext JS uses tables in it's markup to display buttons. If you want an Ext JS format button, rather than just a normal button, you could conceivably include the relevant markup in the groupTextTpl attribute of the Ext.grid.GroupingView object associated with the grouped grid, for example:

```
...
groupTextTpl: 'Item: {gvalue} ({[values.rs.length]} Sub Item{[values.rs.length > 1 ? "s" : ""]}) <table cellspacing="0" class="x-btn  x-btn-text-icon" id="ext-comp-1005" style="width: auto;"><tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left"><tr><td class="x-btn-tl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-tc"></td><td class="x-btn-tr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-mc"><em unselectable="on" class=""><button type="button" id="ext-gen40" class=" x-btn-text my-action">My Action</button></em></td><td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-bl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-bc"></td><td class="x-btn-br"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr></tbody></table>',
...
```

This will create a button in the grouping header.